# Consumer driven contract testing with cucumber

Tags: testing, cucumber, microservices, spring-cloud-contract, integration-testing

I have a rest endpoint in a non spring boot project that I am consuming from a spring boot micro-service. Does anyone know how I can use consumer driven contract test in cucumber step definitions when writing integration tests?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to make a conversion from Cucumber to Groovy DSL. You can read the documentation here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.SR1/single/spring-cloud.html#_custom_contract_converter to see how to add a Contract Converter